Ical.net calendar.GetOccurrences is giving me different results with same input
I am using Ical.net to handle a calendar for a user in my .Net6 application.
I have written a static service that handles the interaction with the Ical.Net CalendarComponents.
The problem is that my unit-test returns the correct result, but when I am running the application, the calendar.GetOccurrences() returns the wrong result.
Here is my static method:
    public static List<DateTimeInterval> GetRecurrenceIntervals(DateTime eventStartUtc, DateTime eventEndUtc, DateTime intervalStartDateUtc, DateTime intervalEndDateUtc, RecurrenceDTO recurrence)
    {
        //Ensure all date-params are UTC-marked
        eventStartUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(eventStartUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        eventEndUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(eventEndUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        intervalStartDateUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(intervalStartDateUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        intervalEndDateUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(intervalEndDateUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        var calendar = CreateUtcCalendar();
        var calendarEvent = AddSimpleEventToCalendar(calendar, eventStartUtc, eventEndUtc);
        AddRecurrenceToEvent(
            calendarEvent,
            recurrence.OccurrenceDays,
            recurrence.Frequency,
            recurrence.Occurrences,
            recurrence.UntilDate,
            recurrence.EveryInterval);
        var occurrences = calendar.GetOccurrences(intervalStartDateUtc, intervalEndDateUtc);
        var intervals = occurrences.Select(x => new DateTimeInterval(x.Period.StartTime.Value, x.Period.EndTime.Value)).ToList();
        return intervals;
    }


Here are the static methods that the above method is calling:
    private static Calendar CreateUtcCalendar()
    {
        var cal = new Calendar();
        cal.AddTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc);

        return cal;
    }

    private static CalendarEvent AddSimpleEventToCalendar(
        Calendar calendar,
        DateTime utcDateStart,
        DateTime utcDateEnd)
    {
        var calendarEvent = new CalendarEvent
        {
            Start = new CalDateTime(utcDateStart),
            End = new CalDateTime(utcDateEnd)
        };
        calendar.Events.Add(calendarEvent);

        return calendarEvent;
    }


Here is my unit-test that returns the 2 event-dates (the 2 expected Thursdays)
(2024-08-22 09:00:00 to 2024-08-22 09:30:00)
(2024-08-29 09:00:00 to 2024-08-29 09:30:00)
    [Fact]
    public void GetRecurrencesWeekdaySameAsStartDayTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var meetingStartUTC = new DateTime(2024, 08, 22, 09, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc); //is a thursday
        var meetingEndUTC = new DateTime(2024, 08, 22, 09, 30, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var recurrence = new RecurrenceDTO
        {
            EveryInterval = 1,
            Frequency = FrequencyType.Weekly,
            Occurrences = 2,
            UntilDate = null,
            OccurrenceDays = new System.Collections.Generic.List<WeekDay> { new WeekDay(DayOfWeek.Thursday) },
            Sequence = DateTimeHelper.GetCurrentEpoch()
        };

        // Act
        var result = CalendarService.GetRecurrenceIntervals(
            meetingStartUTC,
            meetingEndUTC,
            new DateTime(2024, 08, 22, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            new DateTime(2024, 09, 07, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            recurrence);

        // Assert
        meetingStartUTC = DateTime.SpecifyKind(meetingStartUTC, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        meetingEndUTC = DateTime.SpecifyKind(meetingEndUTC, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        Assert.Equal(2, result.Count);
        Assert.True(result[0].Equals(new DateTimeInterval(meetingStartUTC, meetingEndUTC)));
        Assert.True(result[1].Equals(new DateTimeInterval(meetingStartUTC.AddDays(7), meetingEndUTC.AddDays(7))));
    }


When the application runs, it calls CalendarService.GetRecurrenceIntervals with the EXACT same parameters as my unit-test. All dates have DateTimeKind.Utc (which I have double ensured in the method while trying to find the cause)
HOWEVER, only the first event is returned!
Can anyone tell me where the ghost is???
Oh, and the DateTimeInterval is this:
public class DateTimeInterval
{
    public DateTimeInterval(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public DateTime From { get; set; }

    public DateTime To { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(DateTimeInterval other)
    {
        return this.From.Ticks == other.From.Ticks
            && this.To.Ticks == other.To.Ticks
            && this.From.Kind == other.From.Kind
            && this.To.Kind == other.To.Kind
        ;
    }
}


